# Power Query M - Group by Column Value with Custom Aggregation (Percentile)

Tags: powerquery, aggregation, custom-function

I am trying to calculate percentiles by group (from column values ex: hours by department, sales by region, etc.) within power query. This same logic could be used for other custom group aggregation. After lots of searching, I found 2 potential approaches.

**Approach 1:**

[this archived article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a57bfbea-52d1-4231-b2de-fa993d9bb4c9/can-the-quotpercentilequot-be-calculated-in-power-query?forum=powerquery) which looked to have the perfect answer. Nothing else I could find comes close.

The solution from there is the following custom function:

```
//PercentileInclusive Function
(inputSeries as list, percentile as number) =>
let
    SeriesCount = List.Count(inputSeries),
    PercentileRank = percentile * (SeriesCount - 1) + 1, //percentile value between 0 and 1
    PercentileRankRoundedUp = Number.RoundUp(PercentileRank),
    PercentileRankRoundedDown = Number.RoundDown(PercentileRank),
    Percentile1 = List.Max(List.MinN(inputSeries, PercentileRankRoundedDown)),
    Percentile2 = List.Max(List.MinN(inputSeries, PercentileRankRoundedUp)),
    PercentileInclusive = Percentile1 + (Percentile2 - Percentile1) * (PercentileRank - PercentileRankRoundedDown)
in
    PercentileInclusive
```

Combined with a step in your table to group appropriately and use the function:

```
=Table.Group(TableName, {"Grouping Column"}, {{"New Column name", each
    PercentileInclusive(TableName[Column to calculate Percentile of], percentile # between 0 and 1)}})
```

[edited to correct the typo Ron R. pointed out and remove unnecessary detail]

Example input:

| Pen Type | Units Sold |
| --- | --- |
| Ball-Point | 6,109 |
| Ball-Point | 3,085 |
| Ball-Point | 1,970 |
| Ball-Point | 8,190 |
| Ball-Point | 6,006 |
| Ball-Point | 2,671 |
| Ball-Point | 6,875 |
| Roller | 778 |
| Roller | 9,329 |
| Roller | 7,781 |
| Roller | 4,182 |
| Roller | 2,016 |
| Roller | 5,785 |
| Roller | 1,411 |

Desired output for a 25% inclusive percentile grouped by Pen Type:

| Pen Type | 0.25 Inclusive Percentile (Correct) |
| --- | --- |
| Ball-Point | 2,878 |
| Roller | 1,714 |

Notes: No decimals shown above, calculated with Excel's PERCENTILE.INC function.

Approach 1 works great.

**Approach 2:**
Here is an alternate Power Query solution I tried. It is a single step with no custom function. It seems like it should do the trick, but I can't figure out a way to make the conditional check be row based. Something needs to go where I have //Condition// that tells it which rows belong in the current rows group, but no matter what I try it does not work. It either breaks, or gives a percentile for everything, ignoring the grouping.

```
=List.Percentile(Table.Column(Table.SelectRows(#"Previous Step Name", //Condition//), "Column to calculate percentile of"), percentile # 0 to 1)
```

Any ideas how to make approach 2 work?

Comment: If you ***edit your question*** to provide an example of your data (or representative data) (as text which can be copy/pasted) along with a screenshot of the desired output from ***that*** data, and the logic used to obtain those results, it would be useful in trying to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your `Table.Group` function is incorrectly specified.

Where my previous step was `#"Changed Type"`, the following works:

```
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Pen Type"}, {
        {"Percentile", each fnPercentileINC([Units Sold],0.25)}})
```

**Original Data**
[image]

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Pen Type", type text}, {"Units Sold", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Pen Type"}, {
        {"Percentile", each fnPercentileINC([Units Sold],0.25), type number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

**Result**
[image]

***Edit:***
For your approach #2, without a custom function, you can merely use `List.Percentile` as an aggregation in the `Table.Group` function:

```
   #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Pen Type"}, {
        {"25th Percentile", each List.Percentile([Units Sold],0.25)}       
        })
```

Comment: Thanks for the double-check. It was indeed a silly typo on my end that I kept making every time I checked myself. I'm going to clean the original question for future reference. Any ideas on how to make approach #2 work?

Comment: @plasmas222 See my edit. Just use `List.Percentile` directly in the `Table.Group` aggregation.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you.

For anyone referencing this, use the 2nd approach if there is already a built-in function, and use the first when you need a custom function.